# Not allowed to start service Intent X without permission Y

Tags: android, service, android-intent, android-c2dm

```
04-25 14:16:30.931: E/AndroidRuntime(6638): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-25 14:16:30.931: E/AndroidRuntime(6638): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.exclusive26.igale/com.exclusive26.igale.Push_Activity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER pkg=com.google.android.gsf (has extras) } without permission com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE
04-25 14:16:30.931: E/AndroidRuntime(6638):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2553)
04-25 14:16:30.931: E/AndroidRuntime(6638):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:2595)
04-25 14:16:30.931: E/AndroidRuntime(6638):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:121)
04-25 14:16:30.931: E/AndroidRuntime(6638):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:973)
04-25 14:16:30.931: E/AndroidRuntime(6638):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-25 14:16:30.931: E/AndroidRuntime(6638):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
04-25 14:16:30.931: E/AndroidRuntime(6638):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
04-25 14:16:30.931: E/AndroidRuntime(6638):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-25 14:16:30.931: E/AndroidRuntime(6638):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-25 14:16:30.931: E/AndroidRuntime(6638):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
04-25 14:16:30.931: E/AndroidRuntime(6638):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624)
04-25 14:16:30.931: E/AndroidRuntime(6638):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-25 14:16:30.931: E/AndroidRuntime(6638): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER pkg=com.google.android.gsf (has extras) } without permission com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE
04-25 14:16:30.931: E/AndroidRuntime(6638):     at android.app.ContextImpl.startService(ContextImpl.java:867)
04-25 14:16:30.931: E/AndroidRuntime(6638):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService(ContextWrapper.java:336)
04-25 14:16:30.931: E/AndroidRuntime(6638):     at com.google.android.c2dm.C2DMessaging.register(C2DMessaging.java:54)
04-25 14:16:30.931: E/AndroidRuntime(6638):     at com.exclusive26.igale.Push_Activity.register(Push_Activity.java:124)
04-25 14:16:30.931: E/AndroidRuntime(6638):     at com.exclusive26.igale.Push_Activity.onActivityResult(Push_Activity.java:58)
04-25 14:16:30.931: E/AndroidRuntime(6638):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3908)
04-25 14:16:30.931: E/AndroidRuntime(6638):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2549)
04-25 14:16:30.931: E/AndroidRuntime(6638):     ... 11 more
```

The intent does have the proper permission in manifest:

MANIFEST:

```
<permission
    android:name="com.exclusive26.igale.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.exclusive26.igale.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.exclusive26.igale.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
...
...
<activity android:name=".Push_Activity"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
...
...
<service android:name=".C2DMReceiver" />

<receiver android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.C2DMBroadcastReceiver"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <category android:name="com.exclusive26.igale" />
    </intent-filter>

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"/> 
        <category android:name="com.exclusive26.igale" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

chk out the following code in Push_Activity.java :

```
com.google.android.c2dm.C2DMessaging.register( this, com.exclusive26.igale.Config.C2DM_SENDER );
```

parameters sent correctly (Push_Activity context and some email address <-- static final String)
inside  C2DMessaging.register :

```
public static void register(Context context,
        String senderId) {
    Intent registrationIntent = new Intent(REQUEST_REGISTRATION_INTENT);
    registrationIntent.setPackage(GSF_PACKAGE);
    registrationIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_APPLICATION_PENDING_INTENT,
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(), 0));
    registrationIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_SENDER, senderId);
    context.startService(registrationIntent);
    // TODO: if intent not found, notification on need to have GSF
}
```

in the startService() i get the exception. No idia how to solve this.
please shed some light on the subject. Many Thanx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code was correct. I created a new project, copied the code and no problem anymore

Answer (score 13):

Just for future users with this error:
manifest file should look like this:

```
<permission
    android:name="YOUR_PACKAGE.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="YOUR_PACKAGE.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
```

instead of

```
<permission
    android:name="YOUR_PACKAGE.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="YOUR_PACKAGE.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="YOUR_PACKAGE.permission.RECEIVE" />
```

I spend about 5 hours to found out what was wrong in my project :)

Comment: working with phonegap and PushPlugin.
What's interesting is the plugin automatically set the manifest like the first example above and I got the specified error.
Changing it like the second example fixed.

Comment: In case it might help, I had the same lines but different order. My project ran when I ordered just as above

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm missing something but the error shows "com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" and the manifest contains "com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" so I don't see a perfect match.

Comment: I can only define one 'android:permission' in the receiver.

Comment: maybe you can add it to the overall permission section in the beginning?

Comment: the fail point is when triggering the following line (cant debug the code in context.startService ) :       <b>context.startService(registrationIntent);</b> the context is Push_Activity  the intent contains new intent with extras : { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER pkg=com.google.android.gsf (has extras) }    the second EXTRA is : intent.putExtra("sometxt",PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(), 0)); - all this is sent to context.startService(intent);

Comment: I have created a new project with the same code, for debugging purpose and it works! I have no idia why I cant start the service form my original project

Answer (score 0):

This error also can be provide, if we use some resource's names incorrectly in our Activity Java file. I also got the same error, but I did not use any services or permission yet. Problem was at onCreate() method with wrong resource id.