# Android GCM error: java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER }

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

So guys, I'm trying to make an app with GCM, when I launch the app I get the following error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(4215): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER pkg=com.google.android.gms (has extras) } without permission com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE
```

here is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mypackage"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.nfc.permission.NFCEE_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.nfc.permission.NFCEE_ADMIN" />

    <!-- GCM -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.mypackage.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.mypackage.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.NoActionBar" >
        <uses-library
            android:name="com.android.nfc_extras"
            android:required="true" />


        <activity
            android:name="com.mypackage.SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.NoActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.mypackage.gcm.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

                <category android:name="com.mypackage" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name="com.mypackage.gcm.GcmIntentService" 
            android:exported="true"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: inside your `intent-filter` tag of `receiver` put `android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER" />`

Comment: possible dublicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22117317/securityexception-not-allowed-to-start-service-intent-act-com-google-android), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25399845/securityexception-not-allowed-to-start-service-intent-act-com-google-android-c2) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315455/not-allowed-to-start-service-intent-x-without-permission-y)

Comment: put `android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER" />` in your `intent-filter` and delete one of `<uses-permission android:name="com.android.nfc.permission.NFCEE_ADMIN" />`

Comment: Did yu get a solution? I am facing similar troubles

Answer (score 0):

You have twice

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.nfc.permission.NFCEE_ADMIN" />
```

Try to remove one and clean your project.